# python list comprehension with cls

Tags: python, list, class, list-comprehension

I encountered a snippet of code like the following:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ids = [array.index(cls.lower()) for cls in array]
```

I'm confusing for two points:

1. what does `[... for cls in array]` mean, since `cls` is a reserved keyword for `class`, why not just using `[... for s in array]`?
2. why bother to write something complicated like this instead of just `[i for i in range(len(array))]`.

I believe this code is written by someone more experienced with python than me, and I believe he must have some reason for doing so...

Comment: The simple answer is there are a broad range in quality of programmers

Comment: experience != quality

Comment: Nitpicking, but `cls` is not a reserved keyword, just a convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls` is not a reserved word for `class`. That would be a very poor choice of name by the language designer.  Many programmers may use it by convention but it is no more reserved than the parameter name `self`.

If you use distinct upper and lower case characters in the list, you will see the difference:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'B','A','c']
ids = [array.index(cls.lower()) for cls in array]
print(ids)

[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
```

The value at position 3 is 1 instead of 3 because the first occurrence of a lowercase 'B' is at index 1.  Similarly, the value at the last positions is 2 instead of 5 because the first 'c' is at index 2.

This list comprehension requires that the array always contain a lowercase instance of every uppercase letter.  For example `['a', 'B', 'c']` would make it crash.  Hopefully there are other safeguards in the rest of the program to ensure that this requirement is always met.

A safer, and more efficient way to write this would be to build a dictionary of character positions before going through the array to get indexes.  This would make the time complexity O(n) instead of O(n^2).  It could also help make the process more robust.

```
array     = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'B','A','c','Z']
firstchar = {c:-i for i,c in enumerate(array[::-1],1-len(array))}
ids       = [firstchar.get(c.lower()) for c in array]

print(ids)
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, None]
```

The `firstchar` dictionary contains the first index in `array` containing a given letter.  It is built by going backward through the array so that the smallest index remains when there are multiple occurrences of the same letter.

```
{'Z': 6, 'c': 2, 'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'b': 1, 'a': 0}
```

Then, going through the array to form `ids`, each character finds the corresponding index in O(1) time by using the dictionary.

Using the `.get()` method allows the list comprehension to survive an upper case letter without a corresponding lowercase value in the list.  In this example it returns `None` but it could also be made to return the letter's index or the index of the first uppercase instance.

Comment: Here's a bit more elegant way to build `firstchar`, if you want it: `firstchar = {}; for i, c in enumerate(array): firstchar.setdefault(c, i)`

Answer (score 0):

Some developers might be experienced, but actually terrible with the code they write and just "skate on by".

Having said that, your suggested output for question #2 would differ if the list contained two of any element. The suggested code would return the first indices where a list element occurs where as yours would give each individual items index. It would also differ if the `array` elements weren't lowercase.